# How would i use a for loop to transfer funds to multiple addresses in an aray

Tags: solidity

I am creating a airdrop contract, how would i use a for loop to send a value to addresses in an array ?

Comment: That is the worst way to do it

Comment: https://github.com/Anish-Agnihotri/merkle-airdrop-starter

Comment: @MajdTL Airdrop was probably the wrong word more like a multisender, so not a like claim page. Just someway people can come to my dapp and send a token to multiple addresses at once